# How to fix an error when trying to cluster 2 rows in a csv file

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to learn how to cluster a simple data set. 
'suns.csv' is a csv that has just 2 columns of data, id like to do a clustering model via python and the pyclustering package
The code below give me the error 'KeyError: 0'

```
import pyclustering
import pandas as pd
# Read data 'SampleSimple3' from Simple Sample collection.
# sample = read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE3)
sample = pd.read_csv('suns.csv')

kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(sample, [8, 23, 36, 50])
kmedoids_instance.process()

clusters = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
medoids = kmedoids_instance.get_medoids()

for i in range(len(clusters)):
    medoid_point = sample[medoids[i]]

    clusters[i] = sorted(clusters[i], key=lambda index: metric.euclidean_distance(medoid_point, sample[index]))
    print(clusters[i])
    print("\n")
```

I'd like the model to create its own clustering groups and I'd like to plot the model

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv('suns.csv')` returns `DataFrame` or `TextParser`. You have to convert it to list of points represented by built-in `list` or `numpy.array`, something like `[[1.0, 2.3], [1.3, 2.4], ...]`.